# connecting 2 Kinect sensors to my notebook

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox, kinect-interaction

I am trying to connect 2 kinect sensors to my notebook. I know that I have to have at least 2 separate USB 2.0 controllers. According to tis website: [LINK](http://wiki.ipisoft.com/index.php?title=USB_controllers) I have the same settings as in the picture. So I think that connecting 2 kinect sensors should be possible for me. I have 3 regular USB2 ports and one combined with e-SATA. So I have 4 ports to connect USB devices. However, when I try to connect 2 Kinect sensors (each time into different ports), I am always getting error message on one device (in windows device manager):

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)
```

Can anyone help me please? I do not have any other computer and dont want to buy new just because USB controllers. I thing there has to be a way to do this. Thank you

Comment: DO you actually have 2 usb controllers though?

Comment: @RossBille and how / where can I check it? I only see the same as in the picture from that link. I have Controller - 3B34 and Controller 3B3C, 2X Generic USB Hub, 2X USB Root Hub

Comment: @user2179427 what's the notebook your using ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I am using Toshiba Satellite A660 1-GD

Answer (score 0):

can you please get a schematic of your notebook's motherboard and double check how your 3 ports are connected to the 2 controllers you mention. Hopefully 1 out of the 3 ports will be connected to a different controller from other 2 ports.

Does your notebook allow you to connect an express card to it ? Perhaps you could get an additional port this way.

With a custom built PC and a PCI Express USB expansion card we've got 3 kinects connected at the same time for [an art-installation/robotics project](http://www.ruairiglynn.co.uk/portfolio/fsymmetry/).

I remember though at the time getting 2 Kinects running at the same time on my old 2008 macbook with no problems. Note that this was with either the libfreenect and OpenNI drivers, since the Kinect SDK driver doesn't work on osx.

Also, since you're using the Kinect SDK, I'm guessing you are using either Kinect for Windows (v1 if you will) or Kinect for Xbox360 and **not** the Kinect 2 for Windows since the current Alpha release of the SDK currently only allows a single sensor.

**Update**
Had a quick look here:

[image: A660 1-GD dissasembled]

although couldn't easily find the schematics. My guess is two USB ports are connected to the same controller and the 3rd USB port *might*(don't take my word for it, check the manufacturers specs) be connected to a separate usb controller, in which case connecting one kinect to one side of your laptop and the other kinect to the port on the opposite should work. Make sure you see both sensors in Device Manager(run `devmgmt.msc`). 
Also, just to double check your sensors as well, try connecting one, running a demo/test, then disconnecting and using a second sensor on the same port.
If both sensors work individually work on the same port, test them also on the usb port on the opposite side. You just want to make sure neither the sensors nor your ports are faulty. Lastly, if your hardware looks fine (power is good, sensors and ports are good), double check your code and me sure you don't accidentally open the same sensor twice or any other mistake that might be easy to miss.

If you have a friend you can either borrow another laptop for a short time just to test that would also be good. You can also try getting an USB Express Card™ card for your laptop. Although a long shot, you could try to disable other usb devices on your laptop, leaving as much bandwidth available to the ports as possible. You should be able to do this either from Device Manager or your potentially from BIOS settings.

Comment: My notebook is Toshiba satellite A660 1-GD. Unfortunately I can not find any schematics of my motherboard. If you know where can I find it I will be glad.

Comment: An important note: according to the [official Xbox documentation](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/accessories/kinect-for-windows-v2-known-issues#c0f98f7c94a64254a7a8cff46d87638a) on Kinect 2 the device cannot work with USB 2.0 but only with 3.0.

Comment: Yes, that is true, Kinect 2 is USB 3.0 only. The original question was on Kinect 1, not 2, so I didn't add this note, but it's very important to keep this in mind for Kinect 2 projects.